# Mongoose field not required but unique

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have an email field set as unique, but it is not required.

The problem is that if the user does not enter anything Mongoose puts "null" in it. This causes duplicates because every user that does not enter the email field will have "null" assigned to it.

What is the standard practice to avoid this?

Thanks

Comment: How is the default value to be calculated?  What sort of data type is the field?

Comment: it's a string. I guess I could put a random number in string form in it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Use a sparse unique index

> If a document does not have a value for a field, the index entry for
>   that item will be null in any index that includes it. Thus, in many
>   situations you will want to combine the unique constraint with the
>   sparse option. Sparse indexes skip over any document that is missing
>   the indexed field, rather than storing null for the index entry.

`db.collection.createIndex( { a: 1, b: 1 }, { unique: true, sparse: true } )`

More information: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/

Comment: Thanks man! this is what i was looking for

Comment: `MongoDB cannot create a unique index on the specified index field(s) if the collection already contains data that would violate the unique constraint for the index.`